# Undefined function the_post_thumbnail on home page only

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange problem where on my local (Ubuntu) setup, as well as our production and staging environments (also Unix) everything works fine. But on my colleagues (Windows) environment the error "undefined function the_post_thumbnail" shows up on the front-page (and only the front-page).

The strange thing is that it *only* happens on the front-page even though post thumbnails are being used on more or less *every* page.

We are of course adding post thumbnail support (through `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')`). This was (incorrectly I believe (now)) done on the 'init' hook but we have tried 'after_theme_setup' too (both works for me - none for him)).

We tried `die()` inside the same function that calls `add_theme_support()` and the die-text does show up on the front-page which tells me all the code in that function is being run.

How come it works on all other pages but not on the home page (not sure if it's worth mentioning but we are using a static front-page along with the `front-page.php` template as opposed to a blog home page)? How come it's specific to his machine?

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Care to explain downvote?

Comment: its a bit odd how yours works and his does not? Is he running a old version of wp?  if not its something in the set up, i presume windows means lamp stack rather than iis?  . But as a hack you could make use of `if(!function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') ) ....add theme support`

Comment: Yes it's very strange. And no, we both have the latest WP version, and on every other page but the home page it _does_ work for him too (and they all use custom post types too). His version is downloaded from the staging server (where it works) so there shouldn't be any differences in code. Yes, he's using Apache on Windows so that's not it either.

Comment: I meant post thumbnails when I said custom post types above. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: no confusion, technically the static front page is a 'page' post type, but thats not the issue, on my local 4.4.2 with a blank theme and no plugins i cant reproduce, even if i dont add theme support. Anyway good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I can't reproduce it either so I'm thinking it's his Windows environment that's not working properly. Tried to convince him to switch to Ubuntu but he didn't bite :) At least it works in production.

Comment: @David in case you're curious, apparently he was _not_ using the latest WP, and the function in question was in fact `the_post_thumbnail_url` (not `the_post_thumbnail`) which was added with WP4.4. Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for letting me know, i was thinking about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so apparently I was incorrect in two things:

1) My colleague did *not* use the latest version of WP and
2) It wasn't `the_post_thumbnail` he got the error on but `the_post_thumbnail_url`

That explains it because `the_post_thumbnail_url` is a new function from WP4.4.

Leaving this answer here in case someone else runs into this problem too.

Edit: Oh, and the reason it only failed on the home page was because that's the only place the featured image was used as a background image (hence using `the_post_thumbnail_url` as opposed to (the not recently added) `the_post_thumbnail`)